# TestNG tests don't start in IntelliJ 13.1.4

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

I am unable to run or debug any TestNG tests in IntelliJ 13.1.4 on my Mac. When I try to run the test in debug mode, the IDE is hung starting the test - it never completes.

However, I can work with the same test using an older version of IntelliJ (12.1.7).

So far I've tried changing the JDK, replacing the testng jar in ../IntelliJ13/plugins/testng/lib, reimporting all maven dependencies, rebuilding IntelliJ indices.

Any ideas about how to fix my IntelliJ 13.1.4 environment?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue - it turns out that I need to config my JVM options and connection used.

***Update:***

Sadly no, they are internal resources. But the algorithm should be the same (for your case):

- goto `Run/Debug Configuration`
- select `TestNG`
- add your Name for the new configuration
- select path to your test suite in `Suite`
- in `JDK settings` tab, find `VM options` input your connection configs
- run/debug for the `Run/Debug Configuration` - menu arrows

this worked for me.

Comment: Can you list out the config you used?